# alternative elementtype to match styles of an anchor-element

Tags: html, css, sass

I am currently adjusting my navbar and I want to remove the functionality of one anchor in my ul while still matching the style of the other anchors.

I already tried to use an id on the specific li-element and replacing it with a button (just copy-pasting the css), but nothing works so far.

Here is my code pen:
https://codepen.io/gisbert12843/pen/XWKdZXj

The CodePen contains the full CSS ^^

And this is the HTML (highlighted the element by space):

```
<body>
<div class="snap-wrapper">
    <div id="main1" class="snap-box box_1">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="/index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html"><i class="fas fa-cut"></i>
                        Leistungen</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-class">
                        <ul class="dropdown-content">
                            <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Herren">Herren</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Damen">Damen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#FarbenUndSträhnen">Farben und Strähnen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#WellenUndGlätten">Wellen und Glätten</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#EPT">Extension | Perücken | Toupets</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Kuren">Kuren</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Brautservice">Brautservice</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Kosmetik">Kosmetik</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/dist/htmls/covid.html"><i class="fas fa-hands-wash"></i> Covid-19</a></li>
                <li><a href="/dist/htmls/inspiration.html"><i class="fas fa-images"></i> Inspiration</a></li>
                <li><a href="/dist/htmls/jobs.html"><i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i> Jobs</a></li>






                      <!-- trying to remove the a-tag below, while keeping the style -->



                <li class="dropdown"><a href="/dist/htmls/mehr.html"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>Mehr</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-class">
                        <ul class="dropdown-content">
                            <li><a href="/dist/htmls/mehr htmls/impressum.html"> Impressum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/dist/htmls/mehr htmls/datenschutz.html"> Datenschutz</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>






            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main2" class="snap-box box_2">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

And this is the CSS of the specific element:

```
.snap-wrapper .snap-box.box_1 .navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box.box_1 .navbar ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.snap-wrapper .snap-box.box_1 .navbar ul li a {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 23px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #e4e4e4;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I am grateful for any kind of suggestions and help! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `<a>` tag you want to "remove" by a `<span>` (obvioously remove the `href` attribute) and in your CSS add this selector `.snap-wrapper .snap-box.box_1 .navbar ul li span` before `.snap-wrapper .snap-box.box_1 .navbar ul li a` like so

```
.snap-wrapper .snap-box.box_1 .navbar ul li span,
.snap-wrapper .snap-box.box_1 .navbar ul li a {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 23px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #e4e4e4;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: awesome! ^^ had to remove the ".snap-wrapper .snap-box.box_1" on both, but it seems to work!